# Importing and exporting netlogo worlds via python strings

Tags: string, escaping, netlogo, pynetlogo

I am running an ensemble of netlogo models through `pynetlogo`.
Every few steps i export the world to file, perform some minor incantations and then import those worlds from file again and keep running the model.
Works like a charm, very happy.

I wanted however to cut down on the write/read operations on disc and I realized that the extensions `export-the` and `import-a` would output the world string. So I want to:

1. save the `export-the:world` call to the string `saved_world`
2. then re import it through `import-a:world`

Unfortunately when I try do to this, and more specifically:

```
saved_world = netlogo.report('export-the:world')
netlogo.command('import-a:world '+ str(saved_world))
```

I get hit by a torrent of Scala exceptions, the legible few related to illegal characters. My guess is that the conversion netlogo string to java string object to python string and back to command, some escape parameters are lost or added in a way that is illegal.

Has anybody gone through something similar? I tried encoding/decoding the `saved_world` string in many different ways (raw, non-raw, utf8, etc...) but with no success.

Comment: Can you print out what `saved_world` looks like on the Python side?  And then instead of directly running `import-a:world`, `show` the value on the NetLogo side as well?  That might give a clue as to what's going wrong.  Also, what does the `str()` call do?

Comment: Unfortunately a well known problem of `export-the` extension is that the output string is so big that it crashes the netlogo console (at least for wolf-sheep-grass which I am using  as example). So I can't compare this manually.
`str()` in python forces an object to be string. The `pynetlogo` library is not returning a python string, but a Java string object (through `jpype`) so you need to explicitly cast it

Comment: Understood about the console crash for printing the `export-the`.  How about sending it to a file instead and then checking the results there?

Comment: Have you ever figured out how to get around these illegal character errors? I face a similar problem at the moment

Comment: @DeMelkbroer I am sorry but no luck. Had switched to a MESA implementation of that model.